# why WriteMode and append are not working?

Tags: matlab, parameters

**MATLAB**

I'm trying to save multiple images in file
but it save just the frist image of the loop

I tied to use append but it didn't work

the code -> imwrite(output,folderS,'WriteMode','append')

---

### THE FULL CODE:

```
        img1 = imread("try1.pgm");
        img2 = imread( "try2.pgm");
    
    folder = "/Users/myname/Documents/MATLAB/TryImg.tif"
    folder=fullfile(folder,'img.tif')
    imwrite(img1,folder);
    imwrite(img2,folder,'WriteMode','append' );
```

Comment: I don't think the `'WriteMode'` input specification is supported for all file formats. What image format are you using? Please edit the question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: That should work with TIFF files. The only strange thing about your code is the value of `folder`, which becomes something like `/Users/myname/Documents/MATLAB/TryImg.tif/img.tif`. This is not bad, it's just unusual. Previously you had said that you get the error "'WriteMode' is not a recognized parameter", is that still the case with this example code?

Comment: Hello thank you , No I change the file to .tif and now I didn’t get the parameter error . But now the append is not working. 

I used folder  instead of the path directly to solve error “ you don’t have permission to write ”.  

Now my problem is the file has only the first image without the appended image

Answer (score 0):

**THE PROBLEM IS FIXED**

1. 'WriteMode' is not a recognized parameter is fixed
   by using .tif extension to all images and file as
2. (append not working) by using sprintf('%d.tif', k);  inside loop
   to have different name for evey image like 1.tif , 2.tif , ...

THE CODE :

```
for k = 1:10
  % read the images from one file  
  jpgFilename = sprintf('%d.pgm', k);
  fullFileName = fullfile("filename", jpgFilename);
  if exist(fullFileName, 'file')
    imageData = imread(fullFileName );
  else
    warningMessage = sprintf('Warning: image file does not exist:\n%s', fullFileName);
    uiwait(warndlg(warningMessage));
  end
% then ,I did some process in the image 
% after process , save the image 
% find the file path to save the image inside it 
folderCover="/Users/myName/Documents/MATLAB/Cover.tif"
% make name for every image -> 1.tif , 2.tif , 3.tif , ...
jpgFilename = sprintf('%d.tif', k);
 fullFileNameCover = fullfile(folderCover, jpgFilename);
if k ==1  % first time to write 
imwrite(imageData,fullFileNameCover );
else 
imwrite(imageData,fullFileNameCover,'WriteMode','append')
end
end
```